# Drupal print all pages as pdf

Tags: pdf, drupal, export

I have a requirement to provide some functionality where a specific user can hit a button and export all the pages in the site to pdf in one go. I am aware they can do one page at a time, but this could be time consuming navigating the whole site, so I need a solution to do it programmatically..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: -> http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using the Views PDF module?

https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf

Comment: Thanks, Ill investigate and see if it can do what I need - just one button to dump the whole site into a PDF...